# Have problem with VBA Code, warning box keep appearing although all row in input form has been filled

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Sorry if what I'm asking sounds so dumb but I really don't know what is wrong with my VBA code and since I'm new with Excel, I couldn't figure out what I have do wrong.

This is my source code, intended to store information in another worksheet before this it's works fine but as my list growing, it does not work anymore.

**edit:** I have two worksheets. 
Input is where the user form is
IncidentDatabase is where I want to store the information.

```html
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCopy2 As String
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "D10, D12, D14, D16, D18, D20, D22, D24, D26, D28, D30, D32, D34, D36, D38, D40, D42, D46, D48, D50, D52, D54, D56, D58, D60, D62, D64, D66, D68, D70,D72, D76, D78, D80, D84, D86, D88, D90, D92, D94, D96, D98, D100, D102, D104, D106, D108"
    myCopy2 = "D111, D113, D117, D119, D121, D123, D125, D127, D129, D131, D135, D137, D139, D141, D143, D145, D147, D149, D151, D153, D157, D161, D166, D168, D172, D176, D180, D182, D184, D189, D191, D193, D197, D199, D201, D205, D207, D209, D213, D215, D217, D219,D222"
    
    
    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("IncidentDatabase")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = Application.Union(.Range(myCopy), .Range(myCopy2))
    End With
    

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("IncidentDatabase")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = .Range(myCopy).Range(myCopy2)

        If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With historyWks
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With
    
    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

And here is what happened after I try submitting the information.

[image]

Please advise me on how I can fixed this problem.

Comment: Is there a reproducible point it stops working? Can you debug with F8 or set a breakpoint to examine this? And why loop when you can do a direct assignment between historyWks =  myRng ?

Comment: @QHarr to be honest, I'm really new to VBA, like I learned about it yesterday. So I didn't even know what I am doing.

Comment: Essentially myRange has blanks. You need to determine why it has blanks if they are not expected. And is the address of myRange the expected address? You are potentially clearing cells later in code so is there any overlap between these cleared cells and your Counta cell region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
 Set myRng = .Range(myCopy).Range(myCopy2)
```

is the problem. As written it's telling Excel to find myCopy2 inside myCopy - and it's not inside. You want to combine the two by using UNION

```
Set myRange = Union(.range(mycopy),.range(mycopy2))
```

Comment: I see...now I understand where the problem comes from. Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: Now I did that, I encounter this problem on another part Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) it is said that I didn't have variable. How can I solve this?

Comment: Probably best to put that as a separate question with the code for the selectionchange